# PHP/HTML : sending email with background image

Tags: php, http-headers, background-image, html-email

I have coded a script to send an email with a background image.

This is how it starts:

```
    ...
    $headers  = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ". $from . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
    $message  = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/strict.dtd">';
    $message .= '<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></head>';
    $message .= '<body style="background:url(http://www.xxxx.com/assets/background.jpg) no-repeat;">';
    ....
```

Way to often, the background image will not appear on the mail client of the final user. This is caused bu the security settings of the mail client and depends from one client to another.

I know I had the same issue years ago and that there was a workaround.
I remember that it was related to the fact that the picture should be encoded somehow in the header of the message but I just don't remember how and I didn't find any reference about this on the web.

All I know is that it worked most of the time (not always but I know that there's no perfect solution, there are only better solutions than others and the css link option is just a bad one).

Any idea how to encode and embed the picture within the email instead of using a css link ?

Thank you

Comment: Where is the background not showing? Outlook?

Comment: Among other mail clients, yes

Answer (score 0):

You're missing quotes on your background URL. You could also try using the `background=""` HTML attribute on the `body` or the `<td>` that needs a background.

To get it working in outlook, have a look at this:
http://backgrounds.cm/